# How to descend into child directories with and without an additional MAKECMDGOAL

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile where I use a wildcard to descend into all src/* folders and run make in those subdirectories. 
I would like to call `make` in there in two form:

`make src/my-project` and `make upload src/my-project`

With only the `upload` goal it works as expected like this:

```
SUBDIRS := $(wildcard src/*)
UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)
TOPTARGETS := upload

ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Linux)
    MKFILE = Makefile-Linux.mk
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Darwin)
    MKFILE = Makefile-OSX.mk
endif

$(TOPTARGETS): $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(shell cp ${MKFILE} $@/Makefile)
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)

.PHONY: $(TOPTARGETS) $(SUBDIRS)
```

But if I add a second target for `make src/my-project` by appending this:

```
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(shell cp ${MKFILE} $@/Makefile)
    $(MAKE) -C $@

.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)
```

`make upload src/my-project` stops working because it first only runs `make src/my-project`, which now works fine, but then then says `make: Nothing to be done for 'src/my-project'`; The whole `MAKECMDGOALS` isn't being used anymore. For some reason it looks like the first target isn't used anymore.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine the two in the same rule.

A few notes: you typically do not want to run `$(shell)` in a recipe.   The recipe already runs in shell, so it's not only rudundant, but can also cause some unexpected side effects (it will actually try to run whatever the command inside spits out...).

Next, copying the `${MKFILE}` in a recipe where the generated file  is not the target is not good practice.

You may want to try something along the lines of this:

```
$(TOPTARGETS): $(SUBDIRS)

#rule to copy makefile over
$(SUBDIRS:=/Makefile) : ${MKFILE}
        cp $< $@

NONSUBDIRGOALS:=$(filter-out $(SUBDIRS),$(MAKECMDGOALS))

#static pattern rule to do both builds, which depends on makefile
$(SUBDIRS): % : %/Makefile
        $(MAKE) -C $@
        [ "$(NONSUBDIRGOALS)" ] && $(MAKE) -C $@ $(NONSUBDIRGOALS)

.PHONY: $(TOPTARGETS) $(SUBDIRS)
```

---- EDIT ----

updated to create `NONSUBDIRGOALS` which is a list of all goals that are not subdirs.   I also used an `[] &&` construct to ensure if `NONSUBDIRGOALS` is empty then it will not call make the second time.

Comment: I had to swap the lines in the recipe around to make it work because when I call `make src/my-project` the makefile actually executes `make -C src/my-project src/my-project`, which fails with `no rule to make target src/my-project`. Swapping the lines fixes this. 
But even then it descends into `src/my-project` and executes a plain `make` (which works) and then `make src/my-project`. The second one fails. Is there a way to change the rule to only call `make -C src/my-project` or `make -C src/my-project upload` without adding another `src/my-project` goal?

Comment: You would need to properly filter out your directories from your `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` before calling the submake.  I'll edit my answer.